# Georgian citizenship

Tags: air-travel

I am living with Irish citizen and Irish born child.we are planning to travel to Schengen zone. I have currently Russian citizenship and Georgian citizenship. I arrived to Ireland with Russian passport and renewed Georgian  passport 3 months ago.Russians do need visas to Schengen area,but Georgians are free of Visa.The Question is, can I travel with Georgian passport to Schengen zone and returned back with Russian passport.Thank you

Comment: Yes you can.  If the suggested duplicate leaves you with any questions about how to do so, please edit this question and/or post a comment explaining what is unclear.